# Want to perform some action only when the post is successful via UIActivityViewController in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am having an app in which i am using `UIActivityViewController`.

This is the code i am using.

```
 NSString *postText = @"My Text";
    NSArray *activityItems = @[postText];

    UIActivityViewController *activityController =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
     initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityController
                       animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This works fine. When i open Twitter or E-Mail from `UIActivityViewController`, It shows the text i want to share and that is fine.

But ,Now i want to perform some action in my DB only when the post is successful or The E-mail is sent successfully.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
    [activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *act, BOOL done)
             {

                 NSLog(@"act type %@",act);
                 NSString *ServiceMsg = nil;
                 if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail] )           ServiceMsg = @"Mail sent";
                 if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter] )  ServiceMsg = @"Post on twitter, ok!";
                 if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook] ) ServiceMsg = @"Post on facebook, ok!";

                 if ( done )
                 {
                     UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ServiceMsg message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                     [Alert show];
                     [Alert release];
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      // didn't succeed. 
                 }
             }];
```

use the completion handler's "done" parameter to check if completed or not

Comment: Hey dude, how can I know whether I have post successfully? Because even the post is failed indeed, the "completed" remains also Yes/1 – Paradise

Answer (score 4):

`completionHandler` is deprecated since iOS 8.0. Use `completionWithItemsHandler` instead, showing the Swift example here:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: sharingItems, applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, success, items, error in
    if success {
        // Success handling here    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 activityController.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *act, BOOL done, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError)

{
    NSString *ServiceMsg = nil;
    if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail] ) ServiceMsg = @"Mail sended!";
    if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter] )ServiceMsg = @"Post on twitter, ok!";
    if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook] )ServiceMsg = @"Post on facebook, ok!";
    if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage] )ServiceMsg = @"SMS sended!";
    if ( done )
    {
        UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ServiceMsg message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [Alert show];
    }
};
```